Unable to locate DataDog API key configuration in Ruby on Rails application
I'm working on a Ruby on Rails application, and I need to update the DataDog API key that the application uses for sending metrics. However, I'm having trouble locating where the current DataDog API key is configured within the codebase.
I've checked the following locations without any luck:
config/secrets.yml
config/environments/production.rb (and other environment-specific configuration files)
config/application.rb
config/initializers/ directory
Environment variables and any separate configuration files (e.g., .env, env.yml)
I've also searched through the application code (controllers, models, services, etc.) but couldn't find any references to the DataDog API key being set programmatically.
The application is a standard Ruby on Rails application, and I have access to the entire codebase through a Git repository.
Can anyone provide guidance on where the DataDog API key configuration might be located in a Rails application? Or suggest any other potential locations I should check?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional information or context about the application or the setup.
one of devops said, it is a shared config
ba config get -b devops -a devops -e XX-production -r shared-k8s
there's a "fake" application name that you can refer to in XXXX (or look directly for it in Parameter Store)
all secrets created for this "application" are shared with every other project
If a project has its own version of a secret, it will likely take precedence over the shared entity.
What I tried:
I checked the config/secrets.yml file, as this is a common place to store application secrets and credentials like API keys in Rails applications.
I looked in the environment-specific configuration files, such as config/environments/production.rb, thinking that the DataDog API key might be configured differently for various environments.
I searched the main config/application.rb file for any references to the DataDog API key or its configuration.
I examined the config/initializers/ directory, expecting to find an initializer file responsible for setting up the DataDog integration and configuring the API key.
I checked for environment variables, either directly or through separate configuration files (e.g., .env, env.yml), as API keys are sometimes loaded from environment variables.
As a last resort, I searched through the application code (controllers, models, services, etc.) for any instances where the DataDog API key might be loaded or set programmatically.
What I was expecting:
I was expecting to find the current DataDog API key configuration in one of the standard locations used in Ruby on Rails applications, such as:
The config/secrets.yml file, which is a common place to store application secrets and credentials.
Environment-specific configuration files (e.g., config/environments/production.rb) or the main config/application.rb file.
An initializer file in the config/initializers/ directory responsible for setting up the DataDog integration and configuring the API key.
Environment variables or separate configuration files (e.g., .env, env.yml) that might contain the DataDog API key.
References to the DataDog API key being loaded or set programmatically within the application code.
However, despite checking all these locations, I was unable to locate the configuration entry for the DataDog API key used by the application.
